# tabing system active class not adding

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tabing system like :

but when i click i am creating a local.storage but on localstorage i am adding active class to data-attribute its not adding why i dont know.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.localStorage.getItem('last_tab_opened')) {
    var opentab = localStorage.getItem('last_tab_opened');
    localStorage.removeItem('last_tab_opened');

    $('button').attr('data-target') == opentab;
    $('*[data-target="' + opentab + '"]').click(); //working
    $('*[data-target="' + opentab + '"]').addClass('active'); //but not adding class active
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks active" data-target="#email" data-toggle="tab" onclick="openTab(event, 'email')" id="defaultOpen">Email</button>
  <button class="tablinks" data-target="#call" data-toggle="tab" onclick="openTab(event, 'call')">Log a call</button>
  <button class="tablinks" data-target="#notes" data-toggle="tab" onclick="openTab(event, 'note')">Notes</button>
  <button class="tablinks" data-target="#tasks" data-toggle="tab" onclick="openTab(event, 'task')">Create Task</button>
  <button class="tablinks" data-target="#schedule" data-toggle="tab" onclick="openTab(event, 'reminder')">Schedule</button>
</div>
```

using this code for localstorage but here class active is not added on this can anyone please explain or guide me ?? i am stuck here it hold me on same id but not applied the active class on it why this is happening.

Comment: When ever i click on any tab there is an error `"message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: openTab is not defined",`

Comment: You have written half question Please provide more information

Comment: can you try to console the value of openTab ?

Comment: You can use jQuery UI `tabs()`.

Comment: You can chain it: `$('*[data-target="'+opentab+'"]').click().addClass('active');`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use below code as well:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('click', '.tablinks', function(){
       var opentab = $(this).attr('data-target');
       $('.tablinks').removeClass('active');
       $('*[data-target="'+opentab+'"]').addClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
.active{
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #333333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks active" data-target="#email" data-toggle="tab" id="defaultOpen">Email</button>
    <button class="tablinks" data-target="#call" data-toggle="tab">Log a call</button>
    <button class="tablinks" data-target="#notes" data-toggle="tab">Notes</button>
    <button class="tablinks" data-target="#tasks" data-toggle="tab">Create Task</button>
    <button class="tablinks" data-target="#schedule" data-toggle="tab">Schedule</button>
</div>
```